# iPhone UIWebView initial focus?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, focus

I have a simple app with a full screen UIWebView. This contains HTML generated by the app. I respond to clicks on various elements of the page via document.location = "someCommand"

I have to touch the screen once before it will respond to a second touch. It's almost like it is not the focused control.

It is the only view in the app.

How can I ensure that the first time the UIWebView is touched it responds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should simply set it as the `firstResponder` when your view controller is put on the screen.